# can't run commands on remote computer in powershell

Tags: powershell

Hello I am really new to PowerShell but I am learning, my question is, I have figured out how to connect to a remote machine using PowerShell

I'm running PowerShell version 2 on Windows Small Business Server 2008

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Admin01 -Credential domain\user
```

When I am connected to the remote machine I run commands like 'hostname' and 'ipconfig' and I get the following error message:

```
The term 'ipconfig' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spe
    + CategoryInfo          :
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: does cmd /c ipconfig work at all?

Comment: What's the value of PATH environment variable in that shell you open up? And what are the other environment variables? (just say `set` in the shell and it'll list the variables set including PATH). I bet that the shell which is opened is bare, and lacks a bunch of environment variables.

Comment: I tried your command Adil H but it did not work

Comment: Csaba Toth this is what I get when I type set http://cl.ly/image/3Z121a0Y0h2u

Comment: dir $env: should give you what set would give in running that command in a command prompt.

Comment: Check the remote endpoint to see if it is restricted or not: `[management.automation.runspaces.runspace]::DefaultRunspace.InitialSessionState.Commands | Select -first 2`.  The entry for CommandType Application should have visibility of Public and Path/Name value of `*`.

Comment: HI Adil and Kieth were do I need to add the code above? Sorry just starting out with powershell

Comment: Run these commands right after you execute your `Enter-PSSession` command. The command I suggested will then run on the remote session and let you know what applications are available.  It is possible the remote machine's endpoint has been restricted.

Comment: Hi Keith, I ran your command [management.automation.runspaces.runspace]::DefaultRunspace.InitialSessionState‌​.Commands | Select -first 2 and this is what I get back http://cl.ly/image/2X043w0d3m1v